# I am unable to reference QSettings using Qt

Tags: c++, qt

I am running a project that uses Qt. I have installed version 5.10.1 (msvc2017_64). I receive an error that the `QSettings` is undefined. I cannot find the reference in the libraries installed.

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QtWidgets/QApplication>


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QCoreApplication::setApplicationName("Circuit Editor");
    QSettings settings;
    MainWindow w;
    w.setWindowTitle("Circuit Editor");
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: How did you install Qt, try reinstalling with _Online_ installer.

Comment: Did you `#include QSetting`  ?  or as it should be `#include QSettings`

Answer (score 0):

1. Never use `#include <QtModule/QClass>` format of includes. They hide project misconfiguration. Use `#include <QClass>` instead.
2. If you're unsure of what to include, include the entire module and deal with details later: `#include <QtModule>`.

Thus:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#if 1
// entire module
#include <QtWidgets>
#else
// needed classes
#include <QApplication>
#include <QSettings>
#endif

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QCoreApplication::setApplicationName("Circuit Editor");
    QSettings settings;
    MainWindow w;
    w.setWindowTitle("Circuit Editor");
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: if I use them separately, i get errors.
#include <QtWidgets>
#include <QApplication>

Comment: And you should get the errors. **They tell you that you did something else wrong**. Namely - your build folder is misconfigured. If you're building using either cmake or qmake, simply delete the build folder. It'll work then. If it doesn't, then your entire build system is off somehow.

Answer (score 0):

My two cents:

1) You forgot to include the header:

```
#include <QSettings>
```

2) You declared a QSetting object but you are not doing anything with it. Is that what you want to do?

Comment: I am unable to find QSettings in my Qt installation. Which is my main concern.

Comment: Then either your installation is corrupted (do you actually have the qsettings.h file somewhere?) OR you just forgot to set up the project correctly (e.g. if you are using qmake, adding the widgets module to the list of modules to use)